# How to combine linear gradient in background image, opacity and text color change on hover?

Tags: html, css

Div tag contains background image with linear gradient of black and transparent from bottom. On mouse hover state, image changes opacity and the text over the image changes color simultaneously. How to do all this three things aforementioned. [I want to achieve this similar effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hxNx.jpg).

Here is my code:

```css
.container{
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.container::after{
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(
        0deg,
        rgba(0,0,0, 0.8) ,
        transparent 30%,
        transparent
    );
}
.container p{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2rem;
    padding: 0 2rem;    
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: var(--white);
}

.container p:hover{
    color: var(--black);

}
.container:hover{
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div  class="container">
  <img id="image1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1451187580459-43490279c0fa?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1472&q=80" alt="Deep Earth">
  <p id="p1">Deep earth</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put the code you have so far into your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Sclip I edited your question, added a test image from [unsplash](https://unsplash.com), so others understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just needed to do some re-organizing in your CSS so you're selectors were targeting the correct elements. I also added a z-index to the text so it wasn't under the gradient.

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: fit-content;
}

.container::after {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8),
      transparent 30%,
      transparent);
}

.container p {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2rem;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container:hover p {
  color: black;

}

.container:hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img id="image1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1451187580459-43490279c0fa?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1472&q=80" alt="Deep Earth">
  <p id="p1">Deep earth</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you! I just needed to know why you added display: block and width: fit-content to the container

Comment: It was to keep the linear gradient from leaving the container, it was extending the width of the page because you have it set to width: 100% but no width on your container

Comment: Until now, I used to add "display: inline-block" and "max-width" for the images to stay inside the container. "width: fit-content" is the new css property I learned today.

Comment: @Sclip You can use whatever works for you and your project, those were just the two I chose. If you used inline-block and max-width it would be the same result in this scenario :)

Answer (score 1):

I've changed up the CSS a fair bit, I've commented in the CSS code what I've done and why.

```css
/* Body Margin 0 is just for the snippet */
body {margin: 0}

/* Added hidden overflow */
.container {
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

}

/* Use both before and after */
.container::before,
.container::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;

    /* Same as top, right, bottom, left = 0 */
    inset: 0;

    /* z-index to control layer depth */
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Use before to simulate the opacity change */
/* Stops the text from fading as well as the container */
.container::before {
    background: white;
    opacity: 0;

    /* Place above dark gradient so that text is more visible */
    z-index: 2;

    /* Transition to make it look smooth */
    transition: opacity 512ms 0ms ease-in-out;
}
.container::after {
    background: linear-gradient(
        0deg,
        rgba(0,0,0, 0.8) ,
        transparent 30%,
        transparent
    );
}

/* Removes bottom margin/padding from last element */
.container > *:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

/* Set the img to always be 100% of the viewport width */
.container img { width: 100vw }

.container p {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;

    /* Same as bottom: 2rem; left: 2rem; */
    inset: auto auto 2rem 2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 300;

    /* Make sure the text wraps in the right place */
    max-width: calc(100% - 4rem);

    /* Forces text to be above before/after */        
    z-index: 3;

    /* Linear transition here! */
    /* White to black text can look out of sync otherwise */
    transition: color 512ms 0ms linear;
}

.container:hover p { color: black }
.container:hover::before { opacity: 0.4 }
```

```html
<div  class="container">
  <img id="image1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1451187580459-43490279c0fa?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1472&q=80" alt="Deep Earth">
  <p id="p1">Deep earth</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed, there are always different ways of doing the same thing in CSS.